# Which arguments does SetArgSty configure in algorithm2e

Tags: algorithm2e

From the [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e?lang=en) of algorithm2e I was expecting `\SetArgSty` to change the style of arguments from functions in my pseudocode, not some arguments from the keywords algorithm2e uses. So if/for/etc arguments should not be changed and myfun() arguments would be.

However that is not what happens. So, what is `SetArgSty` supposed to configure?

Code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined,algochapter]{algorithm2e}
\DontPrintSemicolon

\SetKwFunction{MyFun}{myFun}

\usepackage{xcolor}

% Use Arial font as default
%
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \KwIn{ \(x\) and \(y\)  }
  \KwOut{ \Result }

  \If { condition } {
    then-clause
  }
  \MyFun{v,nothing} \;

  \caption{This is a caption }
  \label{algo}
\end{algorithm}

\newcommand{\myargfontR}{\textcolor{red}}
\SetArgSty{myargfontR}

\begin{algorithm}
  \KwIn{ \(x\) and \(y\)  }
  \KwOut{ \Result }

  \If { condition } {
    then-clause
  }
  \MyFun{v,nothing} \;

  \caption{This is a caption }
  \label{algo}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Image

[image: Before and after configuration]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\SetArgSty` redefines `\ArgSty`, and `\ArgSty` is typically used when `Arg`uments are set. Arguments here is a very broad term, as you can have arguments to functions, or to keywords, or to conditions...

For example, `\SetKw{Something}{something}` allows you to use `\Something` *or* `\Something{<stuff>}`. In the latter case, `<stuff>` is formatted using `\ArgSty` as it is a possible "argument" to `\Something` (in pseudo-code terms).

A quick search for `\ArgSty` within [`algorithm2e.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/tex/algorithm2e.sty) shows it would have an effect on things defined using

- `\SetKw`
- `\SetKwFunction`
- `\SetKwProg`
- `\SetKwArray`
- `\SetKwSwitch`
- `\SetKwIf`
- `\SetKwFor`
- `\SetKwRepeat`

`\ArgSty` configures most arguments for (virtually) all pseudo-code constructions.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, ArgSty is style used for all sort of arguments of algorithms. So result you obtain is what it is expected. I agree that arguments of function could be in a different typo. 
I will think about to change this in the next coming release.

Comment: So, the arguments mentioned in the documentation, are the arguments to algorithms2e own keyword? But than why would the arguments of my own functions change?